# how to make one model serve the purpose of two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you explain how I could remove the duplication from the associations I've created in a Rails app.  The app allows users to teach different courses, as well as study different courses. The courses that are available for study are the same that are available to be taught. For the purpose of this question imagine there are 3 courses that can be taught and studied, `science, math, english`

The way I currently have the associations is as follows. I created a Target model (which represents the courses available for study) and seeded three courses, `science, math, english`. I also created a Course model (which represents the courses the user is teaching) like this and seeded the same three courses.  Note, in case it's unclear, I called the model "Target" because it represents the subject a user is trying to learn.

```
User 

has_and_belongs_to_many :targets #courses the user is studying 

has_and_belongs_to_many :courses #courses that users are teaching
```

Therefore, I believe I have some unnecessary duplication. Course and Target models will have the exact same data (i.e. the same courses).  Is there a way to create one model (in place of the two Target.rb and Course.rb)  and use it to represent both the courses the user is teaching and studying?

**Update**

To help clarify, I'm just referring to the seeded data to help explain/show what the models are doing, namely that both Target.rb and Course.rb are essentially the same, just playing different role. It's more of a template for future relations between users and targets/courses. For example, I might be studying science but teaching math.

Comment: Why are you seeding data here? According to your design, there can be no targets or courses without any users. Does the seeded data belong to any particular user is it actually a template for future relations between targets/courses and users?

Comment: @NielsB I'm just referring to the seeded data to help explain/show what the models are doing, namely that both Target.rb and Course.rb are essentially the same, just playing different role. It's more of a template for future relations between users and targets/courses. For example, I might be studying `science` but teaching `math`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution below. Are you sure you want one_to_many connection between students and courses - it seems like obvious many-to-many. Anyway, important bit is second association.

```
class User

  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses   #or possibly better has_many :through, your call
  has_many :taught_courses, :class_name => :course, :foreign_key => teacher_id

end

class Course
  belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => :user, :foreign_key => teacher_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

UPDATE:

Code above will create two association. First one is habtm association, which requires another table called courses_users with two columns (course_id and user_id, no id column). This will give you:

```
course.users       #=> list of users taking the course
```

If you want, you can rename this association writing:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :students, :class_name => :user
```

Second association is one_to_many, so you can use it by:

```
course.teacher         #=> return single user or nil
user.taught_courses    #=> return list of courses taught by given user
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Multiple habtm association through two tables (you could prefer one table, but then you need to use has_many :through, which would be probably better in this case anyway.
Schema:

```
create_table "courses" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "courses_students", :id => false do |t|
  t.integer "course_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "courses_teachers", :id => false do |t|
  t.integer "course_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "users" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :class_name => "User", :join_table => :courses_teachers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, :class_name => "User", :join_table => :courses_students
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, :join_table => :courses_students
  has_and_belongs_to_many :taught_corses, :join_table => :courses_teachers
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you clarify how that also includes a user studying courses? is the has_and_belongs_to_many for the courses a user studies, and the has_many :teaches for the courses a user teaches? a bit more detail might make it clearer to me. Thanks if you can.

Comment: I agree that it should be many to many, but the teacher one also should be, therefore is it possible to do something like  `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses :as student` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses as teacher`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have courses.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subject
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

In this design, a course can have many students enrolled and a student can enroll in any number of courses. Each course can have one teacher assigned. A course will have one (string) attribute called subject which is the name, like "math" or "english". The course model could be expanded to contain additional information like classroom number, difficulty, length, etc.

This will allow queries like

```
alice = Student.find_by_first_name("Alice")
alice.courses.last.subject
=> "english"
alice.courses.last.teacher.first_name
=> "Eric"
```

or

```
eric = Teacher.find_by_first_name("Eric")
eric.courses.where(subject: 'math').count
=> 3
```

which shows that Eric is teaching three math classes.

Comment: ok, thanks, but here I'm creating two different type of user models (student and teacher) so I'm not really getting rid of duplication (even though I've now reduced the courses down to one model). See my point? Anyway to deal with that?

Comment: You can create a user model and then subclass it as teacher and student using either Single Table Inheritance (which I discourage) or roles, which I prefer. Students and teachers are quite different entities.